# NullPointerException when using path name to load image file

Tags: java, image, swing, path, imageicon

Looked everywhere and still can't find a solution to this problem while using NetBeans.

When I use the following code to load a file by path:

```
Image owl = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/owl.gif")).getImage();
```

I get a NullPointerException. I read somewhere where it suggested creating a new folder and making it a source file for the project, but that didn't help. I've tried multiple suggestions that I found on this site and others, but I'm not getting any results.

I'm starting to wonder if there is something wrong with the way that I am putting the path in, but I'm doing it exactly the way that it shows everywhere else.  I've tried every combination of every example that I could find to solve this problem for the last couple of days, but nothing is working.

Comment: Is `/images/owl.gif` located at the root of the classpath?

Comment: Please specify how your folder structure is laid out. If this code runs inside a jar then there should be a package (i.e. folder) `images` in it and inside that there should exist `owl.gif`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what do you mean by classpath root?

Comment: @Jeremy A Java application is run with a classpath. Everything in the classpath is considered a resource (a class, an image, a properties file, etc.) and can be retrieved by `getResource()`. If a java class is in package `com.company.model` then it will appear in `/com/company/model/...` relative to the root of the classpath. Think of it as a directory structure.

Comment: Check -> build, images, nbproject, src. Inside images is the file specified.

Comment: Right-Click on images -> Build Path -> use a source folder.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Right-Clicking doesn't allow for option to change build path, but images has been made a source file for the project

Comment: @JeremyJohnson : You should've consulted this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), which contains a link to [NetBeans Doc](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html#package), for that matter :-) though glad you got it sorted.

Comment: @nIcEcOw I kept googling stuff for NetBeans and turned up nothing. Wow. Definitely saving that link to bookmarks if there are any other questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the `images` folder wasn't part of your classpath. In Eclipse, it's not in what they call the Build Path.

Right-click on the `images` folder, select Build Path and Use as Source Folder. The folder will now be added to the classpath whenever you run your application through Eclipse. If you do this, you need to change your path to

```
Image owl = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/owl.gif")).getImage();
```

because now everything in `images` will be put directly on the classpath.

You could instead, make a package called `images` under your normal `src` folder and call it as

```
Image owl = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/owl.gif")).getImage();
```

Comment: Build path is not an option available. The folder images has been included as a source file for the package

Comment: OP would also need to change his path to `/owl.gif`.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Yeah, true that.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal you may have just fixed it with that little alteration. Let me do a quick double check. I got a successful build after dropping "/images" part off the path name, I'm going to see if I can set the image to the frame real quick.

Comment: Successful build and was able to change the IconImage for the frame. Thanks guys. Please reflect edit in answer to help others. All other answers right now say to keep the folder name as part of the path, but getting rid of it solves the problem.

Comment: @JeremyJohnson You're welcome. You can do both, depending on how you setup your source folders and packages.

Comment: Also note that in NetBeans one cannot right click and reveal build path. One must click Run -> Project Configuration -> Customize and from there add the folder as a source under the sources tab.

Comment: @JeremyJohnson Oh wow, I thought you were on Eclipse. My bad.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis lol. It's totally listed as NetBeans in the first line of the question, but it's all good. We got it worked out and I thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

`.getResource()` returns null when it cannot find the resource. That's where you're getting the null.

Your problem is that the path for `owl.gif` is incorrect.