# NullPointerException when using path name to show image in jar file

Tags: java, image, imageicon

I have been asked this question before [Can not get image from a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971052/can-not-get-image-from-a-path), and i try to do the way as this link [NullPointerException when using path name to load image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254620/nullpointerexception-when-using-path-name-to-load-image-file), but it is still not working for me.

I tried delete file and add a new one or create a folder and put this image file in this folder (image/12345.jpg). All those ways are not working.

Could i need to delete all image file and import it all again?? or is there any way i can do it??  Thank you

Because i tried to export exec jar file. it didn't show the image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not get image from a path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971052/can-not-get-image-from-a-path)

Comment: Edit your original question instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `class.getResource("blablabla.png").toURI()` and make sure the file is in your classpath. Open the Jar with zip and check.

Comment: I can't do this with ImageIcon.

Comment: then check if the jar contains the image. open it with 7zip or so

Comment: I mean i can't do it like this 
`ImageIcon loginIcon = new ImageIcon(class.getClass().getResource("1.jpg").toURI);`   Could you tell me where i did wrong?? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to open your Jar and see if the images is in the jar?

Comment: No, it is not in the jar file.

Comment: If you use eclipse, rightclick on your project > properties > tab 'source' > add Folder > chose the folder with your pics > OK

Comment: Thank you, iil, but i didn't see 'source', you mean 'Resource'??, if yes, i didn't see where to add Folder either.

Comment: My bad, forgot something. here's the right way to do it: rightclick project > properties > java build path > tab 'source' > add folder